# Importing External project in Play Application

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Hi I'm trying to reference my external java project in my play framework project. Lets say my structure is:

/workspace
-playProject
-javaProject

I want to be able to call classes of javaProject in my playProject. I did some research and people were suggesting to add this line to my build.sbt:

```
lazy val javaProject = RootProject(file("../rolosRepo"))
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).dependsOn(javaProject).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
```

But still it tells me that  the package com.xxx.xxxx does not exist.

Note: I have included the javaProject in my playProject build path

Comment: Play project is just sbt project. See my [build.sbt](https://github.com/ajozwik/scalania-gist-reader/blob/master/build.sbt) for details. Project `web` is play project and depends on other subprojects

Comment: @AndrzejJozwik so I added these to my build.sbt but it says default#javaProject_2.11;0.1-SNAPSHOT: not found. This is my code: `lazy val javaProject = RootProject(file("../javaProject"))
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).dependsOn(javaProject).enablePlugins(PlayJava)`